# Dataset questions

Tags: c#, dataset

I have two dataset questions.

1. If I change any cell in a dataset, how I can update this change in a database without using an SQL update query?
2. How can I see dataset contents in debug mode (to see the data)?

Answer (score 10):

1. You can't update a database without an `UPDATE` query. That's how updates happen. You can use libraries that abstract this away so that you don't have to see the query in your code, but the query still has to happen.
2. You can see the contents of a dataset in debug mode by adding it to your watch list and clicking the little magnifying glass icon. It opens up a window that lets you look at the tables in the dataset.

Answer (score 2):

You can use LINQ to update data into the database, without using T-SQL Update query.

Comment: Like I said, this still results in an update query, but it might be what Gold means. +1

Comment: I beleive you wont have to write your stored procs and t-sql queries for this. You can achive this using ORM.

Answer (score 1):

What you're looking for is a [DataAdapter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.common.dataadapter(VS.80).aspx). It will manage updating, deleting and inserting changes.

Answer (score 0):

Check this code and adapt to your needs

```
    ///<summary>Update Batch records in DataTable</summary>
    ///<remarks></remarks>
    public void UpdateTables(System.Data.DataTable DataTable)
    {

        if (DataTable.TableName.Length == 0)
        {
            throw new Exception("The DataTable tablename is nedded.");
        }

        if (this.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
        {
            this.Connect();
        }

        try
        {
            string strTablename = DataTable.TableName, strSQL;
            System.Data.IDbDataAdapter dt = null;

            if (DataTable.TableName.Length == 0)
            {
                throw new Exception("Tablename can't be null.");
            }

            strSQL = "SELECT * FROM " + strTablename;

            if (m_DatabaseType == DatabaseTypeEnum.Access)
            {
                dt = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter(strSQL, m_ConnectionString);
                System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommandBuilder cb_a
                    = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommandBuilder((System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter)dt);

                dt.InsertCommand = cb_a.GetInsertCommand();
                dt.UpdateCommand = cb_a.GetUpdateCommand();
                dt.DeleteCommand = cb_a.GetDeleteCommand();

                ((System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter)dt).Update(DataTable);
            }
            else if (m_DatabaseType == DatabaseTypeEnum.SQLServer)
            {
                dt = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter(strSQL, m_ConnectionString);
                System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommandBuilder cb_s
                    = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommandBuilder((System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter)dt);

                dt.InsertCommand = cb_s.GetInsertCommand();
                dt.UpdateCommand = cb_s.GetUpdateCommand();
                dt.DeleteCommand = cb_s.GetDeleteCommand();

                ((System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter)dt).Update(DataTable);
            }
            else if (m_DatabaseType == DatabaseTypeEnum.Oracle)
            {
                dt = new System.Data.OracleClient.OracleDataAdapter(strSQL, m_ConnectionString);
                System.Data.OracleClient.OracleCommandBuilder cb_o
                    = new System.Data.OracleClient.OracleCommandBuilder((System.Data.OracleClient.OracleDataAdapter)dt);

                dt.InsertCommand = cb_o.GetInsertCommand();
                dt.UpdateCommand = cb_o.GetUpdateCommand();
                dt.DeleteCommand = cb_o.GetDeleteCommand();

                ((System.Data.OracleClient.OracleDataAdapter)dt).Update(DataTable);
            }
            else if (m_DatabaseType == DatabaseTypeEnum.Odbc)
            {
                dt = new System.Data.Odbc.OdbcDataAdapter(strSQL, m_ConnectionString);
                System.Data.Odbc.OdbcCommandBuilder cb_c
                    = new System.Data.Odbc.OdbcCommandBuilder((System.Data.Odbc.OdbcDataAdapter)dt);

                dt.InsertCommand = cb_c.GetInsertCommand();
                dt.UpdateCommand = cb_c.GetUpdateCommand();
                dt.DeleteCommand = cb_c.GetDeleteCommand();

                ((System.Data.Odbc.OdbcDataAdapter)dt).Update(DataTable);
            }
            else
            {
                throw new NotImplementedException();
            }

            DataTable.AcceptChanges();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw new Exception(ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

Comment: What's this for? We've had no indication of what @Gold really wants since he first posted the question.