# Edit and update all rows in gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

How to edit and update all rows at once in a `gridview` in *asp.net* from single button click.

Any possible way to use `gridview.EditIndex = -1;` to edit all rows at once?

Comment: Lot of pointers here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/902943/bulk-editing-of-a-gridview-in-asp-net

Comment: Hope this helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4314845/put-multiple-rows-of-a-gridview-into-edit-mode

Answer (score 0):

With built int functionality it's not possible.  To do that you need to implement your own logic.  I'd recommend to look into Repeater control in this case.